# getting panel color

Tags: java

I have a program where i have a button to change the background color to red and another button to set back the default panel color.

How do i get back the default color for panel??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the default color to a variable in constructor or before changing the color with the other button, ie:

```
Color defaultColor = panel.getBackground();
```

And in your default color button:

```
panel.setBackground(defaultColor);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you call `JComponent.setOpaque(boolean)` for the component you're working with.... some Swing components default to opaque == false and just show the color of whatever is behind it (e.g. a button in a textured panel).