# Get default background color of swing component

Tags: swing, colors, background

How to get default background color of swing components?  I mean default background color of JPanel?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739704/getting-panel-color ?

Comment: The fact you asked makes me suspect there is something wrong with the design of the GUI.  What is it about the default color you need that cannot be sorted (better) by `super.paintComponent(g)`?  BTW - A Swing `JPanel` typically (PLAF dependent) has a different BG color than a `JTable` or `JTextField`.  Be wary of thinking you have 'the' BG color.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

To get **DEFAULT** color that panel will use when it is created use:

```
Color color = UIManager.getColor ( "Panel.background" );
```

To get **CURRENT** panel background use:

```
Color color = panel.getBackground ();
```

For a complete list of `UIManager` colour properties, see http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-uimanager-color-keys-list.

Comment: Does it  return the "DEFAULT color that panel will use when it is created"? Or does it return the value after the last  `UIManager.put("Panel.background",color);' ?

Comment: Well, if you want to go that deep - `JPanel` doesn't have a default value at all, it is set from current panel UI instance on UI install. Most commonly it is taken from UI defaults table value under `Panel.background` key. You can, of course, redefine that value - in that case that will be the default panel background color and it will be used for all new panels created after you have redefined it.