# Color of the original GUI window

Tags: java, user-interface, colors, background-color

What are the number parameters of the original GUI window? If I would choose from the color constants, `light gray` is still darker than the original. Please tell me what is inside the `Color c = new Color(-,-,-);` for the original color. Thank you!

Comment: Please be more specific. Maybe you're trying to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739704/getting-panel-color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on the Look and feel you are using, but the Swing background color for `JPanel` usually is `new Color(238, 238, 238);`